# ImageView location on google mapsv2

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Hi I have an Imageview on maps as a marker .. Rather than converting pixel coordinates to latlng how can I retrieve the current position of Imageview with GPS tracking? Is this possible to display the location on maps by retrieving from gps..

Comment: Do you mean you want to use some bitmap to represent user's current location on the map (instead of using the default blue dot)? If so, you should check the [Location APIs](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html) to get the user's current location, then render the bitmap as a `Marker` (check [MarkerOption](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/MarkerOptions) for more detail).

Comment: No.. There is an ImageView set the center of Map, while panning the map stops I was wondering that If I can retrieve the ImageView's current position or not..

Comment: Yes, you can just use the [Projection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/Projection) class.

Comment: Thats what I am talking about Projection class converts Pixel coordinates to latlng ..

Comment: So, basically you want to convert a pixel coordinate to latlng coordinate without using `Projection' class? Then all that I know is to use [GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener) to know the center latlng of the current map.